# First vim function - invalid function

Tags: vim, macvim

I am trying to write my first vim function (toggling hidden chars).
This is what I have so far

```
set nolist
set listchars=space:_,tab:▸\ ,eol:¬
nnoremap <leader>c :call showHiddenChars()<cr>   "<---Calling function here

let g:showhiddenChars_is_visible = 0

function! showHiddenChars()
    if g:showhiddenChars_is_visible
        set nolist
        let g:showhiddenChars_is_visible = 0
    else
        set list
        let g:showhiddenChars_is_visible = 1
    endif
endfunction
```

However when I run it I get the error invalid function showHiddenChars
Any suggestions. This is my first vim function.

Comment: just a minor tip, you do not need all of this, to toggle a option just add a bang after the command `:set list!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User function names must begin with an uppercase letter (unless they are script functions with the `s:` prefix, or autoload functions using the `foo#bar()` syntax).

Change your function name from `showHiddenChars` to `ShowHiddenChars` and it should work as expected.